# Horizontal scroll bar does not working when using ipywidget in Python

Tags: python, scroll, widget, jupyter-lab

I am studying ipywidget in Jupyter lab. What I want is to search a keyword in a data frame, then show the result back. So, the result is a data frame which might be large. So, I need vertical bar and horizontal bar to show all the data. Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Button, Layout
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 4000)

a=pd.DataFrame({'a1':['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb','vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv','abc'],
                'a2':['bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb','eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee','sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss','abc'],
                'a3':['qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr','abc']})

keyword=widgets.Text(
    value='abc',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='keyword:',
    disabled=False
)
#display(keyword)

button = widgets.Button(description="search")
#display(button)

input_widgets = widgets.HBox([keyword,button])
display(input_widgets)

#,width='500px', overflow_x='auto'
#output = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(height='400px', overflow_y='auto',width='1600px', overflow_x='auto'))
output = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(height='100px', width='500px',overflow='scroll'))

@output.capture()
def on_button_clicked(btn):
    output.clear_output()
    display(a)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
display(output)
```

[image]

From the picture, you can see the vertical bar works, but the horizontal bar does not work. You can see the horizontal bar only if you scroll to the end of a data frame, which is not what we usually do. I hope the horizontal bar can show at the end of the area.

Comment: this issue is also tracked in https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2842, https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround is to put the text area widget (without layout) in an HBox widget and that have the following layout

```
box_layout = widgets.Layout(display='flex',
                            flex_flow='row',
                            border='1px solid black',
                            width='140px',
                            height='400px')
```

Answer (score 0):

output.layout.overflow = 'visible'